# The script posts pictures normally, not every text is published error_code': 5. What's the problem?

Tags: python, vk

I can't figure out what's wrong

```py
url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=%s&from_group=1&message=%s&attachments=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (-group_id, text, photo, token)
resp = requests.get(url).json()
print(resp)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This code error is due to a probable bad interpolation. The group_id variable for example is with a - (dash) sign next to it.

The message I got from the API was "User authorization failed: invalid access_token". If you've got something similar. You have to change your code to a better interpolation representation. 

e.g.:

fstring

Comment: The problem was in the text because of the symbol #